# Mount network NTFS drive as NFS

Tags: ntfs, fstab, nfs, nas

I have a NTFS NAS mounted on my Ubuntu PC (11.10) to /mnt/nas2/

I wish to set this up as an network drive so my Windows PC can access it. I've tried directly mounting the NTFS NAS to my windows PC, and I can access the files, but my streaming server software does not work with it.

my

```
/etc/exports
```

looks like this:

```
/mnt/nas2/ 10.x.x.x(rw,all_squash,async,insecure_locks,no_acl,no_subtree_check,nohide,insecure)
```

my

```
/etc/fstab
```

looks like this:

```
//10.x.x.y/GoFlex\040Home\040Public\Media   /mnt/nas2   cifs   username=username,password=password,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,_netdev   0 0
```

Comment: So... you're mounting via CIFS, exporting via NFS, and you want Windows to mount it via NFS? Any particular reason you're not mounting it as CIFS on the Windows machine?

Comment: I tried mounting it on the windows machine, I can access the files, but I can't stream the files using my streaming server. I can do so with a directory from my ubuntu machine mounted as a nfs on windows

Comment: where is your streaming server software running?  on the NAS, on the ubuntu machine, or on the windows machine?

Comment: On the Windows Machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, instead of exporting the CIFS as NFS was the following:

1. As root, open Nautilus
2. Navigate to the folder where the cifs is mounted
3. Right click the folder
4. Click "Sharing Options"
5. Check off "Share this folder"
6. Check off "Allow others to create and delete files in this folder"
7. Check off "Guest Access"
8. Click Ok.